# Arrange data in the table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I've been working to this kind of data in array

```
data:[
    0:{
     name:"Pervies, Peter"
     details:[
        {date:"2017-11-17",start_time:"08:00:00",end_time:"16:00:00"},
        {date:"2017-11-18",start_time:"08:00:00",end_time:"16:00:00"}
     ]
    }
    1:{
     name:"Ming, Edmund"
     details:[
        {date:"2017-11-17",start_time:"08:00:00",end_time:"17:00:00"},
        {date:"2017-11-18",start_time:"08:00:00",end_time:"17:00:00"}
     ]
    }
]
```

> I want the data to be display like this:

[image]

> But it always turn out like this:

[image]

> I use this code below in distributing data in the table

```
<table>
      <thead>
            <tr class="text-center location text-white">
                <th>Employee</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time In / Time Out</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor= "let da of data; ">
            <tr *ngFor= "let s of da.details">
                  <td>
                     <strong>{{da.name}}</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     {{s.date}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="time [value]="s.start_time">
                    <strong>/</strong>
                    <input type="time [value]="s.end_time">
                  </td>
            </tr>
            </ng-container>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

can you help on how I should display my data in the table properly.
**I'm using angular 2**

Comment: Your `details.date` is a string. You will have to convert it to Date object or use a filter that accepts a date string and returns in specific format. About redundant names, you are creating elements on loop of `employee.details`. Instead, create it on employee loop and inside that loop use another loop to create rows for details

Comment: no need it still works even if it's a string

Comment: you need to modify the json response.

Comment: it's a multi dimensional array not a json

Comment: you are worried about date format or Data in first column?

Comment: You are not yet to be check the correct answer. Go and see my answer man. hmm

Comment: @MariaJen If any answer solved your issue then do mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to arrange the data in row and col along with display the date in required format

```
<tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor= "let da of data; ">
            <tr>
             <td [rowSpan]="da.details.length+1"> 
                 <strong>{{da.name}}</strong>
             </td>
            </tr>                   
            <ng-container *ngFor= "let s of da.details">
                <tr>
                    <td > {{s.date | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td><input type=time [value]="s.start_time"><strong>/</strong><input type=time [value]="s.end_time"></td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<table>
      <thead>
            <tr class="text-center location text-white">
                <th>Employee</th>

                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time In / Time Out</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor= "let da of data; ">
                 <td>
                     <strong>{{da.name}}</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <tr *ngFor= "let d of da.details; ">
                     <td>{{d.date | date}}</td>
                     <td>
                    <input type="time" [value]="d.start_time"/>
                    <strong>/</strong>
                    <input type="time" [value]="d.end_time"/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  </td>

            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-attribute-g2p1c3?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: that is not what I'm asking for, can you please read my question again

Answer (score 0):

try this

use `parseDate` custom function in your component

```
parseDate(dateString: string): Date {
    if (dateString) {
        return new Date(dateString);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and call the function where you want convert and the format by this way

```
{{parseDate(s.date) | date: 'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
```

**note:** Also consider `@Saurabh Agrawal`  answer for your table format.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5p6b14?file=app/app.component.html) Result :

[image]

Comment: sorry , just a second

Comment: I use pipe in converting date

Comment: {{ dates | date:"MMM dd,yyyy"}}

Comment: Same as me also using that. You need just convert the string into Date. So am using a `parseDate()` function to convert to date. see you can format only the date, can't format a string. @MariaJen And check the Demo and you can see the full details. The result is same as which is you expected in your question.

Comment: Unclear. Did you see my screenshot? The result is same format. @MariaJen

Comment: you just change the format of the date but not how the data distributed in each person

Comment: @MariaJen that's depend on you design. just set the border of this table `<tr *ngFor="let c of d.details">` in my demo. and see

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

here demo link : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5de5mf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-center location text-white">
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time In / Time Out</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
            <td>{{d.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr *ngFor="let c of d.details">
                        <td>
                            {{c.date}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr *ngFor="let s of d.details">
                        <td>
                            <input type="time" [value]="s.start_time">  
                            <input type="time" [value]="s.end_time">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```